# Search in Table one to many c#

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have 2 tables:
[image]
How can I search for all `OTRequest`s by `userID`

Here's my current attempt:

```
var request = _otrequestRepository.Include("OTRequestUser");
var search = request.Where(x => userID.Equals(x.OTRequestUser.Select(y => y.UserID)));
```

But it returns null

Comment: what is the relation ship between both tables ? is ID column of OTRequestUser table is foreign key in OTRequest table?

Comment: One to many otrequetsuser have requestid is foreign key

Comment: what is the object 'a' refers to?

Comment: it is request.where! i type wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var searchResult = request.Where(request => request.OTRequestUser
                                           .Any(RequestUser => RequestUser.UserId == paramUserId))
                                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query for `search` is incorrect.

```
var search = request.Where(x => userId.Equals(x.OTRequestUser.UserId));
```

Try this one. It will find `request`s having `OTRequestUser.UserId` equals `userId`

----Update----

If `OTRequestUser` is a collection `Request` is having, then I think below query should work.

```
request.Where(x=>x.OTRequestUser.Any(y=>y.UserId == userId))
```

Comment: Request.otrequestuser is icollection then cant .userid

Comment: can u check putting breakpoint what's there in `result` after the first statement?

Comment: oh, so `Request` has multiple `OTRequestuser`?

Comment: in that case, `request.Where(x=>x.OTRequestuser.Any(y=>y.UserId == userId))` I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

try this one , where `UserId` is parameter that you mention

```
var search = request.Where(x => x.OTRequestUser.any(y=> y.UserId == UserId));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your tables are in a database. There is a one-to-may relation between `Users` and `Requests`: every `User` has zero or more `Requests`, and every `Request` belongs to exactly one `User`.

In databases this is normally implemented by giving the `Request` a foreign key to the `User`. Usually the name of this foreign key is something like `UserId`. It is not in your table, but asyou use it in your query, I assume every `Request` has a foreign key to the `User` it belongs to in property `UserId`

The input of the query is a value `userId`, the output that you want is all `Requests` of the `User` with this `userId`. If there is no `User` with this `Id` you want an empty collection.

```
int userId = ...
IQueryable<User> users = ...
IQueryable<Request> requests = ...
var result = users                      // from all users
    .Where(user => user.Id == userId)   // take the ones with Id equal to userId
    .Join(requests,                     // join the result with requests
        user => user.Id,                // from every user take Id
        request => request.UserId,      // from every request taks UserId
        (user, request) => new          // when they match create a new object
        {
            // take only the user properties you plan to use
            Name = user.Name,
            ...
            // take only the request properties you plan to use:
            Title = request.Title,
            ...
        })  
     .SingleOrDefault();
```